# nasm error: parser:instruction expected

Tags: assembly

I'm starting with the assembly now

this is prova.asm

```
_prog   SEGMENT BYTE PUBLIC 'CODE'
    ASSUME CS:_prog,DS:_prog
    ORG 0100H
INIZIO: MOV AH,00H  ;pulisci lo schermo
    MOV AL,03H  ;(clearscreen)
    INT 10H ;
    MOV AH, 00H ;aspetta la pressione
    INT 16H ;di un tasto
    MOV AH, 4CH ;torna al dos
    INT 21H ;
_prog   ENDS
    END INIZIO
```

These are the errors

```
nasm prova.asm
prova.asm:2: error: parser:instruction expected
prova.asm:11 error: symbol '_prog' redefined
prova.asm:11 error: parser:instruction expected
prova.asm:12 error: parser:instruction expected
```

Comment: have you tried moving the `ASSUME` directive ***before*** `_prog SEGMENT ...` ?

Comment: have you tried using a name other than `_prog`?

Comment: Please rephrase your question's title better specifying the problem you are seeking an answer to.

Comment: That code is for `masm` not `nasm`.

Comment: Just for the record: consider accepting answers on questions where it makes sense ;-) ... and welcome to upvote levels, which allows you to show your appreciation not only by accepting, but also by well, upvoting content!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not assembly syntax that supported by NASM. You have to use masm to assemble the code. Also It's written in bad format.